# How to make Service Cache publish aware?

Tags: cache-channel-service, cache, object-cache, brokerquery

Working on Web SDL 8.5, I am dealing with an issue that service cache is not aware of new publication. As such, when a query is executed, the results do not contain the newly published dynamic components. Investigation of the broker database shows that the contents have been published successfully. Also, unpublishing the content occasionally updates the cache and executing the same query to retrieve the dynamic components returns the updated data, but it is not a consistent behavior. I am wondering how I can resolve this issue and make the cache service publish and unpublish aware?

Comment: you mean that the content microservice serves up old versions of the content, even after the item is republished ? Normally, you should configure your deployer microservice and content microservice to point to the same Cache Channel endpoint. Could you share your configurations ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure cache invalidation messaging - see the documentation on this topic: https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-7E728735-073B-4827-AABE-B45592CFF36D

With this in place, the deployer will send messages to the Content Services invalidating whatever has just been published.